# How are xml files merged?

Tags: configuration

Until a few minutes ago I thought I understood how Magento xml files (config, layout, system, api, ...) are merged into one big xml that is later used by the application. Apparently I was wrong.
The question came into my mind after trying to find a solution for [SOAP v2 catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes Uncaught SoapFault exception: Access Denied](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/41090/146).
In the solution I found I had to make the `Mage_Catalog` module depend on one of my custom modules otherwise I would get strange results. Some nodes were not merged. They were overwritten.

I understand that for example these 2 xml sections:

```
<config>
    <some_node some_attribute="attr_value">Some label</some_node>
</config>
```

and

```
<config>
    <some_other_node some_other_attribute="other_attr_value">Other label label</some_node>
</config>
```

when merged, become

```
<config>
    <some_node some_attribute="attr_value">Some label</some_node>
    <some_other_node some_other_attribute="other_attr_value">Other label label</some_node>
</config>
```

But what happens if I have these:

```
<config>
    <some_node>
        <label>Some label</label>
    </some_node>
</config>
```

and

```
<config>
    <some_node attr="value"></some_node>
</config>
```

I thought that it will become

```
 <config>
    <some_node attr="value">
        <label>Some label</label>
    </some_node>
</config>
```

Apparently this does not happen at least for the `api.xml` files. It may not happen for other types of xmls, but most probably it does because the `api.xml` files are loaded fia the same method: `Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration()`.
After all this talk, here are my questions:
**How are the xml files merged? What nodes are overwritten and what nodes are merged?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding they are always merged. If the node *with* attribute came first, it is created with attribute, if the ndoe *without* attributes came first, it is created without attribute.

I.e. the first `<some_node>` is used, any further `<some_node>`s can be understood as references. The children are copied into the first node, but attributes are ignored (unfortunately)

Comment: Aha. So you say that the attributes are overwritten and tags are merged. You might be on to something. I will test this approach and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. You are right. The attributes are not merged. Thanks.